# How to benchmark hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, benchmarking, latency, throughput

I am trying to benchmark my hard disk and find the throughput in Mb/s and latency in milliseconds.

This is my code:

```
public class OneMB implements Timer {
public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {
    OneMB oneMB = new OneMB();
    oneMB.process();

}
public void process() throws IOException{
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile=null;
    try{            
        File file=new File("oneMByte.txt");
        byte[] b=new byte[1024];
        randomAccessFile=new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        randomAccessFile.setLength(1024*1024*10);
        long endLatency=0;
        int i=0;
        long startWrite = this.getTimer();
        randomAccessFile.writeBoolean(true);
        endLatency=this.getTimer();                 
        for (i = 0; i < 1024*10*1024-1; i++) {
            randomAccessFile.writeBoolean(true); //Writes a boolean to the file as a one-byte value.
        }
        long endWrite = this.getTimer();
        randomAccessFile.seek(0);
        randomAccessFile.readFully(b);
        long endRead=this.getTimer();
        double timeTaken=(endRead-startWrite)/1000000000.0;
        double data=10.0;
        double throughput=data/timeTaken;
        double latency=(endLatency-startWrite)/1000000.0;//time for the reception of 1 byte
        System.out.println(timeTaken);
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println("Throughput="+throughput+" Mb/s");
        System.out.println("Latency="+latency+" ms");
        randomAccessFile.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            randomAccessFile.close();
        }
}

@Override
public long getTimer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return System.nanoTime();
}
}
```

I get the output as:

```
56.065550577
10.0
Throughput=0.17836264688538242 Mb/s
Latency=0.057668 ms
```

I have a reasonably fast computer:

- 1 TB harddisk @ 5400 rpm
- Intel i7 with quad core @ 2.1 GHz
- 8 GB DDR3 RAM

Could someone tell me if the throughput would be that low or am I using a wrong approach?

Comment: Just for learning sake.